# Translation of 'verbes symétriques' from French to English

Tags: syntax, terminology, semantics

What do you think is the accurate equivalent *les verbes symétriques* in English?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambitransitive_verb (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivit%C3%A9_(grammaire)#Verbes_labiles)?

Comment: A. M. Bittlingmayer, thank you so much. So far your equivalent is the closest one.

Comment: I think there still is some ambiguity regarding this class of verbs. Ambitransitive verbs can be: intransitive, tranasitive, ditransitive, etc. but 'les verbes symetriques' can only be either intransitive or ditransitive.